# select max(column) from table (column is varchar)

Tags: sql, vb.net, loops, for-loop

I am going to make a invoices then.. they are going to have a id it is not going to be identity, it is not my idea, this is the idea's my professor's. then he want it so..
he didn't want i change id to int, he want it was varchar..
but now i have seen this is as identity.. 
id =1, next id=2, next=id=3.. 
but it doesn't mind he told me in the future it is going to be so..

```
abc000002
abc000003
abc000004
abc000005
abc000006
abc000007
abc000008
abc000009
```

then for that he doesn't want i change it to int
how can i get the last? i want it one plus

next i want it was

```
abc000010
```

how can i do it? i am working on visual basic and visual studio 2008
i can use  a loop-for, or a query for solve it, but i dont know how to solve it

Comment: Will the next id after `abc999999` be `abd000000` ?

Comment: Deleted my answer based on the 'this is my homework' comment you made to it. Please don't ask us to do your homework for you - explain what you're trying to do, show what you've tried so far and tell us what didn't work like you expected, and we'll try to point you in the right direction to figure it out. If we do your homework for you, you won't learn anything and will end up trying to get others to do your work for you in the future. :)

Comment: @Ken please give some hints to this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
select max(cast(substring(my_id, 1, 6) as int)) from my_table
```

You may have to adjust the syntax to suit your flavour of db